# Data type deduction

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a list of values read from a CSV/Excel/text file and want to find data type of it like date/number/float or a string in java.
What is the effective way to find type of those?

```
Eg.,["America","Thailand","Srilanka"] - String
[123,456,789] - Number
[12-11-1990,null,13-09-1989] - Date.
[$300,$450,$500,₹450,€340] - Currency(type of number)
```

Comment: I have tried trial and error method but it is taking too long and hope it is inefficient. Let me know any other possibilities.

Comment: Do numbers and date have always the same pattern? If so, which one?

Comment: simply loop over the data, check if a `"` is present -> String. Or only numerical characters -> Number. Or if the pattern matches a custom Date pattern -> Date.

Comment: Maybe you should add better examples. Why in your above example `null` is considered as `Date`? How do you process the values in Java (just before the check for the type)?

Comment: null is just to indicate that there may or may not be values

Comment: You can look at how yaml performs type detection. http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2766934

Answer (score 1):

Based on the little information provided you might start with this snippet. Amend the detection criteria based on your needs/data.

```
/**
 * Any value which contains at least one `Letter` is classified
 * as String.
 */
static boolean isString(String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(value.charAt(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Any value which contains only `Digits` is classified as
 * Number.
 */
static boolean isNumber(String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(value.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Any value which matches the `Date` pattern is classified as
 * Date.
 */
static boolean isDate(String value) {
    // pattern needs some finetuning not matching invalid dates
    // e.g. 77-88-9999
    return value.matches("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = {
        "America", "Thailand", "Srilanka",
        "123", "456", "789",
        "12-11-1990", "null", "13-09-1989",
        "12.11"
    };
    for (String value : values) {
        String type;
        if ("null".equals(value)) {
            type = "null";
        } else if (isString(value)) {
            type = "string";
        } else if (isNumber(value)) {
            type = "number";
        } else if (isDate(value)) {
            type = "date";
        } else {
            type = "unknown";
        }
        System.out.printf("%-7s: %s%n", type, value);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
string : America
string : Thailand
string : Srilanka
number : 123
number : 456
number : 789
date   : 12-11-1990
null   : null
date   : 13-09-1989
unknown: 12.11
```

Comment: That sure one way of doing it.